# making a variable static private to each thread using openmp

Tags: static-members, private-members, openmp

I need to make `t` static to each thread, how can I do that? I tried this but `t` is not static private to each thread.

```
#pragma omp Parallel
{
    traceRays();
}
...
...
void traceRays()
{
    static float t = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the static variable is not declared in the parallel region, then everytime you attempt to define in the parallel region use: #omp parallel private(t)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by just making `t` threadprivate:

```
void traceRays()
{
    static float t = 1;
    #pragma omp threadprivate(t)
}
```