# openmp, inline functions, and static variables (plain C)

Tags: c, openmp

version 1:

```
inline double func(int i){
    double X;
    X=sqrt(2)*i;
    return X;
}
```

version 2:

```
inline double func(int i){
    static double X;
    X=sqrt(2)*i;
    return X;
}
```

version 3:

```
inline double func(int i){
    static double X;
    #pragma omp threadprivate(X)
    X=sqrt(2)*i;
    return X;
}
```

the `func()` function is then called inside an openmp block, such as:

```
#pragma omp for default(shared) private(i) schedule(static)
for(i=istart;i<istop;i++){
  val[i]=func(i);
}
```

What's the fastest and most safe version of `func()`? Are all three versions flawless?

Comment: What is `X` for in the first place? Aside from version 2 not being thread safe, not much can be told without knowing if/why you need `X`...

Comment: yes version 2 is not thread safe. Why do you declare it static ? In the first version X will be private to each thread, so its safe. Version 3 will have to be tested although at first look it seems safe.

Comment: @Gilles this is just an example, X is the result of a generic calculation that depends on i
@itsnevertoobadtoaskforhelp I want to declare it static because `func` is inside a loop and it's called zillions of times. Since X is static, it does not have to be initialized at each call of `func`.

Comment: Then, well, time for you to experiment and benchmark... My own idea would be that going to a version like #1 and letting the compiler all freedom to optimize is probably the best solution. Version #2 is wrong as already stated. Version #3 is correct, but it think that, best case scenario, it will only be as fast as version #1... Just try it and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles for your comment. I was expecting these conclusions but I was hoping to go into more details, for example why v3 is correct and v2 isn't? Since `func` is inline, the threadprivate directive is called inside a parallel section, and thus it seems unnecessary. Equivalently, due to inline in v2 each thread should create its own `X` variable, with no conflict. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't really see how v2 wouldn't be incorrect... You define a `static` variable `X` which is nothing more than a global storage location, and you access it in rw mode concurrently with several threads... So you will have plenty of race conditions between the reads and writes of the various threads here. The fact that the function is declared `inline` doesn't change its semantic. It only allows / suggest the compiler for further optimization. V3 fixes this issue by creating as many versions of `X` as there are of threads. V1 is just plain simple and safe.

Comment: I see your point. I think it's however a major compiler limitation because in v2 each thread calls a function in which a variable is created, so it's clearly threadprivate; a smart compiler should note the issue, and at least give a warning...

Comment: There is a related post here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269170/making-a-variable-static-private-to-each-thread-using-openmp/39337017#39337017

Comment: This is not "a major compiler limitation", it is only the way the language is defined and works. Maybe it is not the way you think it should work, but ignoring it will lead you to many disappointments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we declare a static variable inside of a function (it doesn't matter inline or not), the compiler will generate a global variable with a unique name (usually combined of the function name and the variable name). The difference between static function variables and global variables is in scope of visibility only.
So version 2 is not thread safe.

Let's compare version 1 and 3. Version 1 is a bit faster due to X being a register, and it's not necessary to store it to main memory. Speed difference doesn't depend on `inline` or `openmp`, so I'll show a simpler example:

```
#include <math.h>

double func1(int i){
    double X;
    X=M_SQRT2*i;
    return X;
}

double func2(int i){
    static double X;
    X=M_SQRT2*i;
    return X;
}
```

Compile it: `gcc -S -O3 test.c`

Here `-S` is to generate assembler file `test.s` and `-O3` is to enable optimization.

```
func1:
.LFB3:
    .cfi_startproc
    cvtsi2sd %edi, %xmm0
    mulsd .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
    ret
    .cfi_endproc

func2:
.LFB4:
    .cfi_startproc
    cvtsi2sd    %edi, %xmm0
    mulsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, X.2782(%rip)
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

We may see that `func2` is one line longer.
Instruction `movsd   %xmm0, X.2782(%rip)` stores result to main memory. `X.2782` is our generated global variable.

So version 1 is better.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when running in a parallel block my v3 is faster right?

Comment: @cipper, No. Version 1 is faster. After optimization (do not forget to enable optimization in your compiler) version 1 doesn't have the variable X at all.
And version 3 has an additional instruction to store X in main memory.

Comment: And use `M_SQRT2` instead of `sqrt(2)`. It will make your loop several times faster. A compiler (at least `gcc` and `g++`) can't understand automatically that `sqrt(2)` is a const.

Comment: The X=sqrt(2)*i operation was just an example, generally I have much more complicated stuff there. I think that your argument holds only in very simple cases, where the compiler can avoid to define the X variable. Otherwise v3 should be faster starting from the second call.

Comment: I can`t agree. If optimization is enabled the compiler tries to avoid all local variables. Usually it leads to a significant speed-up. You may write some test programs and measure the time. If v3 happens to be faster - please, show your code.